# Does document inherit from window?

Tags: javascript

I was under this impression.

But I found out that

```
window.FormData
```

exists while

```
document.FormData
```

does not exist.

I would have expected the interpreter to look up the prototype chain, when it did not find FormData in document.

Does document inherit from window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) and [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) are two totally different objects.

Comment: document is a property in window.  I found it strange you did not mention this.

Comment: Well, that wasn't your question. I did provide links to the DOM reference where you could read up on the subject. 
You might also like to know that `window` is on the top of the scope chain, meaning all the global functions and objects are defined in `window`. This also means that the `window.` part in  `window.document` is optional (unless there's already a locally defined variable called `document`).